# can I put password to individual database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin/wampserver. Is it possible to add a password on a database?Because my problem is I cannot access the whole thing(http://localhost/phpmyadmin) in my web browser if I put a password on it.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. What platform are you on? What tools are you using to administer the database? How did you set up PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing that, i suggest you put a password to the mysql account you are using in connecting to mysql thru phpmyadmin. then, edit the field relating to the 'password' of the mysql account you are using in the config file of you phpmyadmin app... just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

what do you need the password for?  you can create 2 users of the db - one for select/view only privs and another for full privs